# Change defined function to lambda function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def char(word):
    lower = word.lower()
    for letters in lower:
        number = letters.count('a')
    return(number)
```

I have a defined function above, and I'm trying to change it into a lambda function. How should I do that? :)

---

(updated) how about this function below? I tried to count all 'a's in a word, but looking at the comment it seems like I was wrong. If the code below is in the right direction, how to convert to lambda function?

```
def number_of_vowels(word):
    i = 0
    lower = word.lower()
    for char in lower:
        if char in 'a':
            i += 1
    return(i)
```

Comment: `char = lambda word: word.lower().count('a')`

Comment: Do you want the lambda function to do all the useless extra work that your function does, or do you just what to get the same result? (By the way, you really should not name your function `char` or the variable `lower`, since they are used in Python.)

Comment: @Amadan yep fixed

Comment: You should look again. The loop in the OP's function means that the function returns `1` if the last character is `'a'` or `'A'` and `0` otherwise (and an error for the empty string). The rest of the string `word` is ignored since those values are overwritten. So a better answer is `word[-1].lower().count('a')`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Oh, good catch. Why would someone want that? OP, are you sure that's what you want? o.O

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Neither `char` nor `lower` are names of built-ins in Python. There is a `chr` function, and `str.lower` is a method, but neither of those would be name shadowed by a function named `char` or a variable named `lower`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton clearly my seeing skills need work. `char = lambda word: int(word[-1].lower() == 'a')` last one hopefully

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Primusa: Although technically, if `word` is the empty string, your code will raise `IndexError`, while the original code would raise `UnboundLocalError`. Pretty sure it's impossible for a `lambda` to assign to a name (not until 3.8 releases anyway, with [PEP 572's assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)), so a `lambda` can't simulate that behavior at all; it won't be able to read an unbound local because the only locals are arguments, which are always bound.

Comment: @ShadowRanger lambda has been assignable to a name for some time... it's even in PEP8 which tells you to use `def` instead of assigning lambda to a name.

Comment: @Primusa: Not what I meant. Obviously the `lambda` itself can be assigned to a name. I meant that if you call `char('')` (where `char` is the OP's `def`-ed function), it will raise `UnboundLocalError` (the loop never executes, `number` is never assigned, so `return number` raises that exception). If you do it with your `lambda` equivalent, it will raise `IndexError` instead (because `word[-1]` doesn't exist). You can assign a `lambda` to a name, but you can't assign to a name *within* a `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @RoryDaulton My intention of the code is to count all 'a's in the word. In that sense, the function above is not right? :) I'm new to python world.

Comment: @aquantum: Your original function is looping over the word so each `count` call is on a single character of the `word`. Since you reassign `number` rather than accumulating the results, it's effectively just returning `1` if `'a'` is the last letter in the word, or `0` if not. If the goal is just to count the `'a'`s (case insensitive) in the whole of `word`, it should be `def char(word): return word.lower().count('a')` or `char = lambda word: word.lower().count('a')` as a `lambda`.

Comment: @aquantum can you explain why you're trying to turn this into a lambda? It can be done in this case, as the function is relatively simple, but in many cases, using a defined function is actually the better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
def number_of_vowels(word):
    i = 0
    lower = word.lower()
    for char in lower:
        if char in 'a':
            i += 1
    return(i)
```

is just a very long way to spell:

```
def number_of_vowels(word):
    return word.lower().count('a')
```

which (despite the name) only counts `a`/`A` characters, not all vowels. The `lambda` equivalent would be:

```
lambda word: word.lower().count('a')
```

If you wanted to make it count *all* vowels, that's still possible with the `sum` function and a generator expression:

```
lambda word: sum(1 for let in word.lower() if let in 'aeiouy')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the easiest way is directly use `str.count()`:

```
lambda word : word.lower().count('a')
```

And if you'd like to use something like your code, namely, use `for` loop instead of `count()` method, then use list comprehension in your lambda expression:

```
lambda word : sum([int(letter == 'a') for letter in word])
```

If you want to count more vowels or just more letters, use two args:

```
lambda word,letters : sum([int(letter in letters) for letter in word])
```

And thanks for the correction from @ShadowRanger, in the earier version, I mistakely added a `if word else 0` statement in each expression, which is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Why bother with `word.lower().count('a') if word else 0` over the simpler `word.lower().count('a')`? At best you're *barely* speeding up the uncommon case (empty strings) by slowing the common case of non-empty strings, not to mention writing even more code to no real purpose.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh, thanks for your correction. That's my fault.